# What part of my code does not pass the Simple Array Sum tests of Hackerrank?

Tags: java, arrays

I am doing the Hackerrank questions to get better at solving puzzles. I've been working on the Simple Sum Array question in the Data Structures section for nearly 2 hours O_O

I seriously thought I solved it because I tested it on the terminal on my mac and it ran fine, but when I submit the code in Hackerrank, it failed all 3 test cases T_T

I don't understand where the problem is and why the test cases failed. Does anyone see the problem? Please help.

Below is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static int sumArray( int[] arr ){ //arr stands for the array to pass in
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            result = result + arr[i];
        }

        return result;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Print out the size of the array: ");
        int size = input.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[size];

        System.out.println("Type out the numbers you want in the array. One line only, each number is separated by a space");

        String numbers = null;

        String[] splitString = null;
        while ( input.hasNextLine() ){
          numbers = input.nextLine();
          splitString = numbers.split("\\s");

          if (splitString.length == size){
            break;
          }

        }
        //splitString = numbers.split("\\s");
        int i = 0;
        for (String s : splitString){
          //System.out.println(s);
          array[i] = Integer.parseInt(s);
          i++;
        }

        System.out.println( sumArray(array) );

    }
}
```

Also, here's the Hackerrank question to clarify what they wants:

Given an array of  integers, can you find the sum of its elements?

**Input Format:**

The first line contains an integer, denoting the size of the array. 
The second line contains space-separated integers representing the array's elements.

**Output Format:**

Print the sum of the array's elements as a single integer.

**Sample Input:**

```
6

1 2 3 4 10 11
```

**Sample Output:**

```
31
```

Comment: Are you talking about [Simple Array Sum](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/simple-array-sum) in **Algorithms**?

Comment: Did you try the `Run Code` button, instead of the `Submit Code` button, which runs your code with the given sample, and **fails**, because of your two `println()` statements printing text? Output should be `31`. *Nothing else.*

Comment: I ran your **exact** code 6 times with various numbers and it worked perfectly

Comment: Andreas - Ah, my mistake. It's not Data Structures - I'm talking about the Simple Array Sums in Algorithms. You were right about the println statements!!! Once I commented them out, my code passed the test cases!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score -2):

From the first time seeing your code you have two issues:

```
1- arr.length should be arr.length - 1
```

Because, your iteration starts from 0 and length not

```
2- the way you print your array is wrong
```

Because, you should use something like this:

```
Arrays.toString(array)
```

Comment: 1) `for` loop condition is `i < arr.length`, which is correct. If you changed to `i < arr.length - 1`, the loop would skip the last value, so you're wrong there. --- 2) OP is not printing the array anywhere. What are you talking about?